# How to add autocomplete part to html input field

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a input field with ajax which returns list of elements matching with the input.

```
<input name="sku_id" type="text" placeholder="SKU" class="form-control" autofocus>

$('[name="sku_id"]').on('keyup', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var sku_id = $('[name="sku_id"]').val();

    if ( sku_id.length > 2){
        $.ajax({
            url : "/sku_auto/",
            type : "POST",
            data : {action:'search_sku',
                    sku_id:sku_id},

            success : function(response){
                var sku_list = response.sku_list;
                console.log(sku_list);
            },

            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The ajax returns a list of elements. I want to ask how to display the list below the input?

Most examples recommended using `JQuery-ui's autocomplete` feature, but on using the cdn it is messing with the rest of code.

I want to know if i have to write the css for this or i can append it directly?

Comment: You can use jQuery with .noConflict(). The answer to this question is actually rather complex.

Comment: Ok,,,but how will it catch the list my ajax query is returning....Can you explain a little more?

Comment: If you don't need to support IE9< or Safari, use a [datalist](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/markup/whats-new-in-html5-forms-the-datalist-control.html#fbid=lWlc794HNGb)

Comment: @RobinDorbell What is the input in the function in your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a list of the items recieved and append it to some kind of container. Here's an example:

```
function createAutoCompleteList(sku_list, input) {
    var container = $('<div class="autocomplete-container">');
    var ul = $('<ul>').appendTo(container);

    $.each(sku_list, function (index, item) {
        var listItem = $("<li>").append(item);
        //You can add click event to the item here.
        ul.append(listItem); 
    });

    input.after(container);
}
```

When you have this container you'll need some CSS. Another example:

```
.autocomplete-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Something along these lines should work.

Comment: what is the input here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with your custom jquery and css code, Just do some modification in your jquery code as following :-

```
$('[name="sku_id"]').on('keyup', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var sku_id = $('[name="sku_id"]').val();

    var listItem = "<ul>";

    if ( sku_id.length > 2){
        $.ajax({
            url : "/sku_auto/",
            type : "POST",
            data : {action:'search_sku',
                    sku_id:sku_id},

            success : function(response){
                var sku_list = response.sku_list;

                $.each(sku_list, function (index, item) {
                    listItem += "<li>"+item+"</li>";
                });
                listItem += "</ul>";

                $(this).after(listItem);
            },

            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

It may help you.